# in java8 how to a define a function with custom code only?

Tags: java-8

I want to send two kinds email, and some logic could shared. e.g.

```
try {
    MimeMessage msg = javaMailService.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, DEFAULT_ENCODING);
    //custom code here ...
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    logger.error("build email fail", e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("send email fail", e);
}
```

above is common code (e.g. sendEmail(Function customCode)), below is custom code of sending email to foo

```
logger.info("send count mail to {}", toFoo);
helper.setFrom(sender);
helper.setTo(toFoo);
helper.setSubject("Foo Subject");
String content = generateFooContent(foo); //use fooTemplate.ftl
helper.setText(content, true);
javaMailService.send(msg);
```

I want to this effect,

```
Function fooFunc = ()->{logger.info("send count mail to {}", toFoo);
    helper.setFrom(sender);
    helper.setTo(toFoo);
    helper.setSubject("Foo");
    String content = generateFooContent(foo);
    helper.setText(content, true);
    javaMailService.send(msg);}
```

then call `sendEmail` method,

```
sendEmail(fooFunc);
```

If I want to send bar message,

```
Function barFunc = ()->{...} //cunstom code here
sendEmail(barFunc);
```

In java8 could achieve this？ if could how?

Answer (score 3):

Your "Function" has a signature:

```
void doStuff(MimeMessageHelper helper)
```

We already have one of these - it's called a `Consumer<MimeMessageHelper>`.

So:

```
final Consumer<MimeMessageHelper> messageCreator = ...
try {
    MimeMessage msg = javaMailService.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, DEFAULT_ENCODING);
    messageCreator.accept(helper);
    javaMailService.send(msg);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    logger.error("build email fail", e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("send email fail", e);
}
```

Now, to define your `sender` simply use:

```
BiConsumer<MimeMessageHelper> fooFunc = helper -> {
    logger.info("send count mail to {}", toFoo);
    helper.setFrom(sender);
    helper.setTo(toFoo);
    helper.setSubject("Foo");
    String content = generateFooContent(foo);
    helper.setText(content, true);
}
```

P.S. please note my formatting.

Comment: Thanks!  but still have a question please see my below post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Boris the Spider， it do works, see below

```
private void sendFooHtmlMessage(List<Foo> body) {
    BiConsumer<MimeMessage,MimeMessageHelper> fooFunc = (msg,helper) -> {
        logger.info("send foo mail to {}", toFoo);
        try {
            helper.setTo(toFoo);
            helper.setSubject("Foo Subject");
            String content = generateFooContent(body);
            helper.setText(content, true);
            javaMailService.send(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    };
    sendMessage(fooFunc);
}

private void sendMessage(BiConsumer<MimeMessage,MimeMessageHelper> consumer) {
    try {
        final MimeMessage msg = javaMailService.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        helper.setFrom(sender);
        consumer.accept(msg, helper);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        logger.error("build email failed", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("send email failed", e);
    }
}
```

but still lack something, see above code I have to catch exception in `fooFunc`, actually I want to throw it because in common `sendMesage` will catch these exception.

So I adopt another way， see below

```
public interface SendMessageAction {
    void action(MimeMessage msg, MimeMessageHelper helper) throws MessagingException;
}

private void sendMessage(SendMessageAction action) {
    //...
}

private void sendFooHtmlMessage(List<Foo> body) {
    SendMessageAction fooAction = (msg, helper) -> {
        logger.info("send foo mail to {}", toFoo);
        //...
    };
    sendMessage(fooAction);
}
```

Comment: First, rewrite your answer as a full answer - not a comment referencing my answer. Second - if you are going to use your own functional interface; annotate it with `@FunctionalInterface`. Third, see my answer - you don't need a `Message` in the parameters and you should just populate the message in the callback, send the message in the common code.